# HTML Email Rendered Incorrectly When Carriage Returns Are Not Used

Tags: python, html, email, html-email

The following python script generates an email file that can be piped to sendmail.  When I send this to my gmail account, lines 25, 50, and 51 are not what I would have expected.  All other lines appear as expected.

```
import sys
print "From:test@test.com"
print "To:you@you.com"
print "Subject: test no carriage return"
print "MIME-Version: 1.0"
print "Content-Disposition: inline;"
print "Content-Type: text/html"
sys.stdout.write ("<html>" )
count = 1
while ( count < 55):
 # output without a carriage return 
 sys.stdout.write( "<tr><td>test" + str(count) + " no carriage returns!</td>")
 count = count + 1
sys.stdout.write ("</html>")
```

In the email I would expect this for lines 25,50,51:

```
 test25 no carriage returns!
 test50 no carriage returns!
 test51 no carriage returns!
```

instead, this is rendered:

```
 test25 no carriage retur! ns!
 test50 no ca! rriage returns!
 test51 no carriage returns!        test52 no carriage returns!
```

If I change the output to use `print` instead of `stdout`, then the email displays as expected.  I have also tried this in an MS Outlook with the same effect.  What is the reasoning for the unexpected result when carriage returns are not used?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a typo, but for one thing you are not closing your row. You are missing a:

```
</tr>
```

As well as opening and closing table tags.

Comment: Thanks @ptutt. I updated the script with closing tags on the row as well as opening and closing table tags and still encountered the problem.  In this case, lines 26 and 46 had unexpected results. Line 22: `test22 no carriage returns! !` . Line: 46: `te! st46 no carriage returns`

Comment: The new output file that I generated with the closing tags does validate with an HTML validator tool.